# UIScrollView with huge contentSize scrolls slowly

Tags: ios

Is there a way to configure UIScrollView to scroll faster with larger contentSizes?

Comment: increase size dynamically. example when adding or removing subviews

Answer (score 0):

The memory requirements of UIScrollView is very high in case you have large amount of data.

If you have very fixed amount of data, then UIScrollView is fine.

But if you want to manage large amount of data, I recommend that you use UITableView with customizations.

Because, in UIScrollView, you will have to know the size of your data and **allocate** memory based on that. Hence, the memory for content size of 50000 high is allocated and then you will be able to scroll.